# Primitive recursive and Turing machines

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

Can someone give me a hint or the start of a possible proof for the following theorem:

> A function $f: \mathbb{N}^r \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is primitive
>   recursive if and only if there is a primitive recursive function
>   $t:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and a $t(n)$ time bounded Turing
>   Machine $M$ that computes the function $f()$.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly does it mean for $t(n)$ to bound the time of $M$?

Comment: A Turing Machine $M$ is time bounded by a function $t(n)$ if for all $n$ and for all $w$ (with $|w|=n$), the computation of the Turing Machine $M$ on $w$ is finite and that the length of the computation is at most $t(n)$.

Comment: Have you tried, for the "only if" direction, showing that each of the basic functions has such a $t$ and $M$ and that having such a $t$ and $M$ is preserved by composition and primitive recursion?

Comment: And for the other direction you might use a characterization of primitive recursive as computable according to Church-Turing but without using unbounded search.